# Does Parse.com's Crypto library support PBKDF2?

Tags: parse-platform, pbkdf2

A lack of documentation for a `crypto` library available from Cloud Code in Parse.com suggests I should look elsewhere. But I have found it to support AES encryption and some hashing.

I can't see any PBKDF2 support.

Can anyone confirm if Parse.com Crypto supports PBKDF2? And do you have an API example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default crypto library offered up by Cloud Code does support PBKDF2 so there is no need to attempt to port another library into the framework.

e.g.,

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var SALT_LEN = 32;

function randomSafeBytes(len) {
    return crypto.randomBytes(len)
    .toString('base64')
    .slice(0,len)
    .replace(/\+/g, '0')  // replace '+' with '0'
    .replace(/\//g, '0'); // replace '/' with '0'
}

function generate_key(password) {
// get a brand new key
    var salt = randomSafeBytes(SALT_LEN);
    return {
        salt:salt,
        key:generate_key_from_salt(password, salt)
    }
}

function generate_key_from_salt(password, salt) {
    // regenerate a key from a given salt
    var ITERATIONS = 100000; // tune this figure to balance platform/needs
    var KEY_LEN = 32;
    return crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt.slice(0,SALT_LEN), ITERATIONS, KEY_LEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it in cloud code personally, but [here's a relevant post from Parse that addresses your question.](https://www.parse.com/questions/documentation-for-parse-cloud-code-module-crypto) With regards to the crypto module in cloud code,

> It's the general node module that can be found here:
>   http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html

Crypto does support PBKDF2 and if you need a newer version of the module, you can load the module directly by placing a copy in your cloud/ folder and using require('cloud/crypto')